# Why have I been banned from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I have no down voted questions.

Of a total of 8 questions I have 7 up votes and 0 down votes.

I have a 51 reputation which is very low but however it is one nonetheless.

And yet I am excluded and I'd like to know why please?

I have contacted the Stack Overflow people and get no reply.

If I cannot improve on my already up voted questions, what other measures can I take to be allowed back in?

Comment: Was a banning reason given?

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: How many questions of yours have been deleted (either by you or by moderators)?  The deleted questions count against you.

Comment: There is some kind of weird vendetta against me, others have picked up as well. I try and laugh about it but it is really frustrating.

Comment: Well I didn't know what to do if a question didn't suit so when that was alerted I would just delete it. I don't know how many- it doesn't say.

Comment: Now see people are down voting me again - I really don't know why...pack mentality?

Comment: Look under "recently deleted questions" in your profile.  They should be there.  If not, flag one of your posts and request that your other questions be undeleted.  I have a feeling you're not telling us the whole story here.

Comment: I am absolutely telling you the whole story here.

Comment: I once came into this place and was extremely abusive in retaliation, that is only thing but I apologised.

Comment: Well, if that's the whole story, then all you have to do is undelete them and improve them.  The ban is automatic, it will remove itself once the questions are improved.

Comment: @cea "Now see people are down voting me again" -- they are all after you.

Comment: All of the information you need is in the duplicate.  You should have already read it, though, as you were provided a link to it.

Comment: You have 13 deleted questions, almost all of them downvoted. That's the reason that you were banned from asking. Almost all of those were questions about setting up software, and were closed as being off topic because they were outside of the scope of a programming site. I don't see how these can be edited into something that fits this site, but if you truly wanted to ask more programming questions here, you could write the SE team (via the contact form linked at the bottom of every page here) and ask that the worst of these be dissociated from your account.

Comment: They don't bother to reply unfortunately. I see people on a daily basis ask similar questions to mine and they are not down voted. I can only assume it is my phraseology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably deleted some of your negatively voted questions. Although they don't reflect on your reputation total, they do count towards whether you can ask more questions.

Comment: +1, given all the other comments this seems the most likely reason.

Answer (score 4):

You need to work out on the way you provide questions. SO is not a chat, you need to provide more context. For example:

> Does www-data translate as apache for ownership?

Reading the question body alone it's really hard to say what is asked there. I've edited it, I hope it's what you've wanted to ask.

Questions with poorly defined context are likely to be flagged as low quality. We (non-mods) don't see also deleted questions/answers. Another issue is the possibility there's other user that was banned in the same IP (or anonymous questions as well).

If you have problems with improving a particular question, feel free to ask there. Please note, that if the question is too broad, opinion based or asking for recommendation, so clearly off-topic, your meta post is likely to be dowvnoted as well. Ask only if you have problems with formulating the specific problem, which you feel is perfectly on topic.

**Don't** ask duplicate questions on meta, for example 2 posts about why you've been blocked. It's likely to attract downvotes as well, making things worse instead of better.